# Minimize the maximum magnitude of several quadratic functions

Tags: optimization, quadratics, nonlinear-optimization, non-convex-optimization

I have a collection of quadratic functions

\begin{align}
f_i(x) = \frac{1}{2}x^T Q_i x, \qquad i = 1,\dots,m,
\end{align}

where each $Q_i$ is an indefinite $n \times n$ matrix and $x \in \{-1,1\}^n$. I wish to solve the following optimization problem

\begin{align}
\text{minimize}  &&\max \limits_i |f_i(x)|
\end{align}

which has a nonlinear objective function.

What approaches exist for attacking this kind of optimization program? Is there a more powerful approach than using a general purpose global optimizer?

Note: In response to a comment, I've realized that I need to change the condition on $x$ to generate the desired problem. In particular, I need $x \in \{-1,1\}^n$ instead of $x \in [-1,1]^n$.

Comment: You know that for $x=0$ the maximum is $0$, so you can consider the intersection of the regions where all the functions are nonpositive.  It could be the intersection is the origin and you are done.

Comment: Good point! This made me realize that I really do need $x \in \{-1,1\}^n$ to avoid this (undesired) solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is nonconvex both from the indefinite quadratics, and from the combinatoric $x$. The way I would approach it is by first writing the absolute values as $-t \leq x^TQ_ix \leq t$ with objective $t$, and then exactly linearize the quadratic terms.

Since I am lazy, I will write the linearization for binary $x$ (scale and shift accordingly for your case). Terms $x_ix_j$ are replaced with $w_{ij}$ which satisfies $w_{ij}\leq x_i$, $w_{ij}\leq x_j$ and $w_{ij} \geq x_i + x_j-1$. At this point you have a standard mixed-integer linear program in $x$, $w$ and $t$.

Comment: Reading a bit in "Integer Programming" by Conforti et al., and also in "Optimization in Integers and Related Extremal Problems" by Saaty helped me understand this answer.

Answer (score 1):

Introducing optimization variable $t \in \mathbb R$, the optimization problem can be written as follows

$$\begin{array}{ll} \text{minimize} & t\\ \text{subject to} & -t \leq \mathrm x^\top \mathrm Q_1 \mathrm x \leq t\\ & -t \leq \mathrm x^\top \mathrm Q_2 \mathrm x \leq t\\ &\qquad\quad\vdots\\ & -t \leq \mathrm x^\top \mathrm Q_m \mathrm x \leq t\\ & -1_n \leq \mathrm x \leq 1_n\end{array}$$

Comment: I noticed this was possible, but it was unclear to me how this helps. Is this in a standard form? The presence of the objective in the constraints seems unusual to me.

Comment: Well, it is a way of getting rid of the $\max$. The problem remains non-convex.

Comment: Would this allow for optimization using something other than a general purpose global optimizer?

Comment: How big is your $n$?

Comment: I'm interested in $n$ from $n=7$ to $n \approx 200$.

Comment: It's late, I am tired, and I may be missing something obvious, but imagine introducing $n+n=2n$ slack variables. There may or may not be slack. That is $2^{2n}$ cases to consider. If $n=200$, that is something close to $2.58 \cdot 10^{120}$ cases.

Comment: If I understand correctly, that means this approach won't be feasible in this case, unfortunately.

Comment: I suspect it's not just this approach that is hopeless...